# Swatch cronjob won't execute

Tags: cron

I'm trying to execute a swatch command via crontab in Ubuntu 10.4. The command works perfectly in the command line but not in cron.

Here is the command :

```
/usr/bin/swatch -c /home/administrator/swatch.conf -f /home/administrator/scripts/couchdbmonitor.log > /home/administrator/scripts/swatch.log 2>&1
```

I see the job triggering in `/var/log/syslog` but does not execute.

Comment: and what is in your `/home/administrator/scripts/swatch.log` ??

Comment: It's the output that would usually print to the command line. The output looks something like "*** swatch version 3.2.3 (pid:12684) started at Mon Jul 23 14:46:02 EDT 2012".